# How to initialise data to different components in React

Tags: reactjs

I am learning React and trying to complete some Frontmentor advance projects.

I am building a movie app with different pages like a home page that list all the movies, a movie page that list only the movies, a TV Series page and a bookmarked pages. Also a json data provided.

The json data has this kind of structure.

```json
 {
    "title": "Beyond Earth",
    "thumbnail": {
      "trending": {
        "small": "img",
        "large": "img"
      },
      "regular": {
        "small": "img",
        "medium": "img",
        "large": "img"
      }
    }
    "year": 2021,
    "category": "Movie",
    "rating": "PG",
    "isBookmarked": false,
    "isTrending": true
  },
```

My question is: What is the best way to manage this json data, as it will be consumed by all the different pages on their initial load ?

Keep in mind that users should be able to change the isBookmarked status when a button is clicked. Should I used, RTK, or context or store in a remote db and manage with React query?

I am using these projects to learn different technologies but want to know the best for each situation.

My initial process was to use a redux toolkit, but later learnt that reducers should be pure. Also thought about creating a database for the data in supabase but ran into problem on how to create the db with this data structure.

I currently have a local storage hook that loads to that to local storage and can return the value and setValue for the movies. But don't know  how that can be consumed by all components

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing you can do is to create a context that can be used to easily pass the data to all the components

A context is created like this :

```
const MoviesContext = createContext({});

export function MoviesProvider({children}) {
  const [movies, setMovies] = useState([]);

  // Here you put your method to fetch the movies. It is just like
  // doing it in a classic functional component

  //  I didn't see any id in your json, but it is better to use 
  // id instead of index
  const bookmark = (index) => {
     const clone = structuredClone(movies)
     clone[index].isBookmarked = !clone[index].isBookmarked;
     setMovies(clone);
  }
  
  return (
    <MoviesContext.Provider value={{movies, bookmark}}>
      {children}
    </MoviesContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

Then you wrap your parent component with the provider. Every component using the context should be called as a children of `MoviesProvider`

```
<MoviesProvider>
  <Content />
</MoviesProvider>
```

Note that if you use `react-router` and all your pages will need the context, you can put `<Routes />` as a child of `<MoviesProvider />`

And then, in every child components, you will have acces to the context with the `useContext` hook :

```
const {movies, bookmark} = useContext(MoviesContext);
```

You can also create a shortcut in your context file

```
export const useMovies = () => useContext(MoviesContext)
```

So you just have to call it that way

```
const {movies, bookmark} = useMovies()
```

And that's it !

You can also pass props to the provider if you want to initialize some values from above.

`Context` in React are very useful so if you want to learn more i suggest you read the documentation :

- [useContext](https://react.dev/reference/react/useContext)
- [Passing Data with context](https://react.dev/learn/passing-data-deeply-with-context)

Also don't hesitate if you have any question, or if my answer doesn't go far enough

Comment: Thanks so much for the detailed reply. I will implement this.

Also on another note,  how can I pass data into a redux store when the  app first initialised? since the reducer has to be a pure function.

Comment: You can still fetch the data before calling dispatch, that way the reducer will still be a pure function and won't contain any logic. And to do that at first render, you can use a useEffect hook with an empty dependency array to trigger the data fetching, and then call the dispatch function with your reducer

Answer (score 0):

if you wanna haved data to diffrent componets .

you can context , redux-toolkit , zustand , and other ..

what tools is better ? this your qustion .

this deppend for project ..

if you need handle so much api and diffrent api or data you redux-toolkit is good option .

if your project is not big project just simpel or medium project useContext is good option .

deppend on your project .

for work with api :

react-query is good option .

if you have  redux-toolkit in your project you can use RTK-Query .

other option is axios can help you for manage api